# Can I use multiple docker networks in plain Rancher OS?

Tags: docker

I try to rebuild a simple *docker-compose* setup in *Rancher OS*, but I can't find any hint about the supported version in [Rancher docs](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/system-services/custom-system-services/).

Is it possible to automatically create docker networks (and docker volumes) via Rancher OS custom services? Or is this out-of-scope for plain *Rancher OS* and only possible via a full *Rancher* installation?